# Which EPSG for UTM with 8 digits in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, coordinates, epsg, utm

I have a UTM datasets with 8 digits, so the first digits are 32 (for UTM Zone 32N), but which EPSG should I use to get the data at the right spot in QGIS in a 6 digits system.

If I want to transfer UTM coordinates with 6 digits to 8, I think I could use EPSG 5652 (ETRS89 / UTM zone 32N (N-zE)) but which one I should use to get a 8 digit value to the 6 digits type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your dataset should appear in QGIS with EPSG:5652. If not, use `Set CRS for Layer` to get it.

The 6-digit CRS is EPSG:25832. Rightclick on the layer, `Save As ...` under a different name and that CRS, and add it to the canvas.

It might be even enough if you just change the **project** CRS to EPSG:25832, leaving the dataset unchanged.